# reload jquery dialog content past ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have a page with dialog. In the dialog i have another button for mysql table update. I can't reload the dialog past ajax confirm success...
The issue i think is caused by the fact that the code window is on another php file and this file can not run "(this).dialog". In fact even .dialog.close() goes.
probably the second file is not recognized as a dialog... ?

in index.php

```
$("#edt").load("edt.php" + id); <div id="edt" title="edit"></div>
```

in edt.php

```
$.ajax({....
success: fuction() {
$(this).dialog.('close');
```

How to close dialog? And... how can i reload dialog content?
If i write

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

so reload all page, not only dialog... :(
Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Try passing 'this' as a context parameter in your AJAX call.  That should give you the reference to your window on success.

```
$.ajax({....
context : this,
success: function() {
$(this).dialog.('close');
```

For future reference, you can set whatever you want for the context value and it will make that item available to reference using 'this' in your success function.

Answer (score 0):

It's too confusing to me what you want to do. As advice, first of all the `$(this).dialog.('close');` is not gonna work inside the success callback because it's a function and $(this).dialog does not exist there.

You should keep it in a variable when you create the dialog box and execute it later or bind this with success callback function.

Comment: how can i set variable when i create dialog box?
In $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: var dialog = $( "#dialog" ).dialog();, dialog.('close');

Comment: I'm back. re-explain.. i have the div content (of dialog) in a separate php file (edt.php). When i click button, dialog open and load the second file. In this file $(this).dialog not work. I would like to specify that all php file is a dialog and then i think $(this) working... Maybe if i put <div id=dialog></div> on header and footer of this file would solve?

Comment: why you don't have the js code for the ajax request about the edit.php file inside the index.php and keep the form inside the edit.php?